# JSONObject.append into object - result is nested array?

Tags: java, json

Following code produces a nested array as a result for keys containing three items:

```
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject;
// ...

JSONObject ret = new JSONObject();
for (Key key:keys) ret.append("blocked",key.id());
```

The result is:

```
{"blocked": [[["1"],"2"],"3"]}
```

Is this expected? If it is, how can I construct a plain array adding item by item?

Comment: this depends on which library you use, could you specify the full package name for JSONObject

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to create a `JSONArray` object:

```
JSONObject ret = new JSONObject();
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
arr.put("1");
arr.put("2");
arr.put("3");
ret.put("blocked", arr);
```

The result is:

```
{"blocked":["1","2","3"]}
```

Comment: I would say this is more a work around. As Thomas says, the append function should do the same but more compact.

Answer (score 3):

It's curious because the [API says the following](http://jettison.codehaus.org/apidocs/org/codehaus/jettison/json/JSONObject.html#append%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29):

> Append values to the array under a key. If the key does not exist in the
>   `JSONObject`, then the key is put in the `JSONObject` with its value being a
>   `JSONArray` containing the value parameter. If the key was already
>   associated with a `JSONArray`, then the value parameter is appended to it.

But it doesn't work correctly. When I do:

```
JSONObject o = new JSONObject();
o.append("arr", "123");
o.append("arr", "456");
```

I get an Exception saying that "`JSONObject[arr] is not a JSONArray`". It looks like there is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem. You should use the **put** method; not the **append** method. And, of course, you should create a JSONArrray and use that as the second argument of the **put** method.