# JSONObject.append - result is nested array?

Tags: java, json

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11297200/jsonobject-append-into-object-result-is-nested-array) and understand the answer, but can not use it in my scenario.

My scenario: I retrieve data via `JPA` from a mysql database and want to put this data into a `JSONObject` like this

```
{
  "A":["1","2","3"], 
  "B":["1","2","3","4"], 
  "C":["1","2"]
}
```

The problem is I do not know how many arrays I will retrieve. It could be 1 or it could be 200, depending on the data in the database.

If I `append` the data into a `JSONObject` like this:

```
import org.apache.tapestry5.json.JSONObject 
// ...
JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
for (Value val : values) data.append(val.getName(), val.getValue());
```

I'll get

```
{"val_name": [[["1"],"2"],"3"], ...}
```

Is there a way to use `JSONOBject.append` *without* creating JSONArrays and `put`ing them into the `JSONObject`, which will result in a nested `JSONObject`?

Comment: Which library are you using?  What's the full classname of `JSONObject`?

Comment: I am using the `JSONObject` library from tapestry: `org.apache.tapestry5.json.JSONObject`

Comment: Can you use any other libraries?

Comment: I don't understand the desire to avoid the `JSONArray` object? There's no other way for the API to infer your intent in the general case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JSON object is a "dictionary" -- a map between name and value.  A JSON array is a sequential list of values, with only the ordinal position of the value identifying it.  It makes no sense to "append" to the object -- you add new name/value pairs to it (although they apparently call it appending, just to confuse you).  If, within an object, you want something like `"A":["1","2","3"]` then you necessarily must *insert* an array (as the value of a name/value pair) into the object.

But note that either before inserting the array into the object or after you can append additional values to the array.  You just need to get/save a reference to the array.

In your above example you're making the mistake of appending to the object rather than the array.